# Is there a way to wait os.remove() to complete?

Tags: python, windows, file-io, wait

Is there a way to wait os.remove() to complete? I have a script that makes some png pictures every day and deletes the old ones first so the pictures being made are really the updated ones from the old ones.

The problem is - I guess - that os.remove() doesn't have enough time to complete because the files being made are the very same that the ones being deleted. But if I put a time.sleep(5) after the os.remove() it works.

The code is something like this

```
...some imports

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(trgt_folder):
    [os.remove(os.path.join(root, file)) for file in files if 'png' in file]
make_and_save_newpics(trgt_folder)
```

Comment: Don't use a list comprehension if you're not trying to construct a list. It makes your code unclear.

Comment: Loop checking `os.listdir(trgt_folder)` until no PNG file is found. Unfortunately you can't use `os.path.isfile` or `os.path.exists` because they call `stat`, which will fail even if the file still exists because 'deleted' (but not yet unlinked) files are in a state that prevents opening them for any access. The better check in Windows is via `FindFirstFile` with the pattern "*.png". However, Python's standard library has no direct support for this function. It just has `listdir`, which is relatively expensive if the directory has thousands of files.

Comment: Normally this isn't a problem. `remove` calls WinAPI `DeleteFile`, which calls `NtOpenFile` to get a handle, `NtSetInformationFile` to set its delete disposition, and `NtClose` to close the handle, which should immediately unlink and delete the file in the filesystem's `IRP_MJ_CLEANUP` routine if there are no other references to the file. A potential problem is an anti-malware program that opened a second reference to scan the file, which leaves the file briefly in a zombie state (deleted disposition but not unlinked) until the second reference is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a better solution if you overwriting the same file , Instead of giving a time.sleep(5) , why not to give a check if file exist , then remove the file save again :

```
import os
# put this check before file save operation
if os.path.isfile(filepath):
    os.remove(os.path.join(root, file))
    # save new pic after this 
    make_and_save_newpics(trgt_folder)
```

there will be much better ways to do if time is a constraint , time.sleep(5) is not a good approach

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to wait for completion of os.remove(), I would suggest you to use threading. 
invoke os.remove() in a thread and wait for it to complete.