# Folder takes too long to be deleted (wait for os.rmdir to finish)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function that deletes empty folders until a folder with content is found. The problem is that when a child is deleted, the loop iterates *so fast*, that when `listdir` is used to check if the parent is empty, the child still pops up. (Though I haven't tried it yet) I suspect that when I add a `sleep(0.1)` after the delete call, it will work. But that isn't a proper solution to the problem. There needs to be a way to wait until the folder is completely, for sure, deleted before continuing.

The function (simplified) can be found below. When the `rmdir` function is called, and we loop back to the top and reach `listdir`, the folder deleted in the previous iteration sometimes still pops up.

```py
def delete_empty_folders(top_folder: str, root_folder: str) -> None:
    """Keep deleting empty folders until we reach a folder with content
    or the root folder"""

    while True:
        if not exists(top_folder):
            top_folder = dirname(top_folder)
            continue

        if samefile(top_folder, root_folder):
            break
        
        if listdir(top_folder):
            break

        rmdir(top_folder)
        top_folder = dirname(top_folder)

    return
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590779/is-there-a-way-to-wait-os-remove-to-complete) SO page didn't help.

Comment: You shouldn't need any sleep at all if this is a POSIX-compliant filesystem; `os.unlink()` is a synchronous call: when it returns, the directory entry is guaranteed to be gone; if it's not, the filesystem is noncompliant. And if it's _not_ a POSIX-compliant filesystem, nothing about its behavior is guaranteed at all without knowing the _specific_ filesystem and what guarantees it documents itself.

Comment: So, backing up, what _is_ the filesystem? (I wonder if it might be NFSv3? The synthetic creation of dotfiles to represent unlinked content would be consistent with the problem you describe).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy doesn't necessarily help if the FS rms dirs asynchronously. I'd probably look at how [`shutil.rmtree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) works as I'd assume they encountered the issue at one point.

Comment: @Masklinn, right, but any filesystem that does deletion async is wrong. POSIX doesn't allow it, so that filesystem is broken by definition, and _all_ software running on top of that filesystem is going to be unreliable unless it goes out of its way to implement workarounds. (Yes, wrong/unreliable-by-nature filesystems exist, but that's _why_ some software doesn't support running against files stored on NFSv3 f/e)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that doubly does not matter: it doesn't matter because the Python standard library is not specified by POSIX and does not exclusively run on POSIX systems, and it does not matter because OP apparently has that actual issue, telling them "it's not an issue because that problem is illegal" is not a solution.

Comment: Did you forgot to call recursively the function?

Comment: @Masklinn, "Store your files on a better-supported filesystem" is _certainly_ a solution. It may not be a solution the OP can execute on without involving their sysadmin team, but it's a solution nonetheless. And even on Windows, deletion is async as well for FAT and NTFS.

Comment: @Masklinn, and more to the point, _we need to know what the actual semantics are_ before we can devise a good workaround. If we don't know the actual filesystem, we can't look up the actual semantics. This might be as simple as adding a `fsync()` call on the directory within which an unlink happened, but without knowing the filesystem and looking up its particular caveats, _we don't know_.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy "Go fix the Windows API and filesystem" is not in any way a solution, as you apparently are aware deletion on windows "is asynchronous" (the deletion request will return but may only be effected once all handles are closed, at the very least, there may be other edge cases where a deletion is queued but not immediately performed).

Comment: @Masklinn, that's only if you're using non-default flags; typically a deletion will fail outright in Windows if a file has any open handles.

Comment: @Masklinn, again, do we even know that the OP is on Windows? You're arguing hypotheticals we haven't established! I'm asking for more information, I'm not telling them to shove off.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy incorrect, other processes (e.g. windows services, FS watchers) can take a handle on a directory and keep it alive through a deletion success through no fault of the author, [there are even BPOs on the subject](https://bugs.python.org/issue15496).

Comment: Good to know -- hasn't been my platform for a lot of years. But again, we don't know if that's relevant until the OP tells us their platform and their filesystem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy one of your comment literally asserts that an FS which does not follow POSIX is "broken by definition", and that "any filesystem that does deletion async is wrong".

Comment: Yes -- I'm making multiple lines of argument, obviously, but some of them are more directly relevant to finding the OP a suitable workaround than others. And I might admit to a bit of smug-UNIX-head posturing occasionally in some of those less-relevant lines. :)

Comment: @Masklinn, ...even in the broken-by-nature argument line of argument, though, I _did_ say that we need to know what the _actual_ filesystem is to be able to determine what guarantees it _does_ offer before this question can be answered; I've been consistent on that line throughout, and I don't see how it's really open to question.

Comment: Okay I'm gone for 20min and I return to this haha. The application is shipped to >80k people that run it on Mac, Windows, Linux and everything in between. The drives range from m.2 SSD's to network mounted HDD's (I have an SMB HDD share). So hopefully there is a cross-FS solution, or a solution that works for the most used filesystems. The application is distributed via a Linux docker container, so at least it should support that (but there are people that don't use docker but have a manual install instead; that's why it could be all OS'es).

Comment: why not just try to delete it, and see what the os says? rmdir will fail instantly if the directory is not empty. `os.listdir` is a very unoptimal way to check if a dir is empty anyway. Better use `os.scandir` which iterates

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I would still have the same problem. It will try to delete the folder but error out because there is content, even though there isn't anymore. Currently I list the contents to check. Forcing rmdir will also just check if it has content. The problem would persist. On top, making the algorithm more optimal with scandir would be bad in this case. The algorithm is _too_ fast, so we for sure shouldn't go make it even faster.

Comment: @Cas assuming you know the directory should be deletable, you could just handle failure by retrying in a short loop (maybe with some backoff), rather than pessimistically wait, probably retry a handful of times then give up with an error (as that might mean FS activity actually added content back). The more complicated version is to use into the (OS specific, possibly missing) FS events systems, and wait until you receive the deletion event, but that would be a lot more complicated to implement.

Comment: And people comment that SO is becoming toxic... Thanks for proving them wrong, all.

Comment: @Masklinn but I can only know if I can delete the folder by checking that it's empty (which fails if we do so too quickly after issuing the delete for the child). What I could do is say that when supposedly there is content, wait for 0.2s and check again to ensure before stopping. Thought: Maybe a network mounted folder will delete async, which is why I'm encountering this?

Comment: @cas yes that's what I was thinking by "failure", instead of having `if listdir(top_folder): break`, have a loop around which tries a few times (potentially with a backoff) that way if everything deleted synchronously (or at least quickly) there's no sleep, and if the deletion is async there's just a bit of sleeping, there's more on actual failure but that's likely a case you're happy sacrificing anyway.

Comment: Unless there is a better way, I indeed think that's the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR of the comments:

The problem is that in certain setups (OS, filesystem, network mount or not, etc.), files and folders are deleted asynchronously. This means that there is time between when the folder is 'submitted for deletion' and when it is actually deleted. In this time, my algorithm would already have iterated once more and would have reached the `listdir`, where the supposedly deleted folder pops up (because it has been *marked* for deletion, but hasn't actually *been* deleted yet).

There is no way to wait until an async delete instruction has completed in Python. I fixed it with the following (simplified) alternate version of the algorithm:

```py
from os import listdir
from os.path import exists, join, samefile
from shutil import rmtree

def delete_empty_folders(top_folder: str, root_folder: str) -> None:
    """Keep deleting empty folders until we reach a folder with content
    or the root folder"""

    parent_folder = top_folder
    child_folder = None
    
    while parent_folder:
        if exists(parent_folder):
            if samefile(parent_folder, root_folder):
                break

            if listdir(parent_folder) not in ([], [child_folder]):
                # Folder has content and it's not only the empty child
                break

        child_folder = basename(parent_folder)
        parent_folder = dirname(parent_folder)

    lowest_empty_folder = join(parent_folder, child_folder)
    rmtree(lowest_empty_folder, ignore_errors=True)

    return
```

This version doesn't delete each folder individually. It immediately searches for the lowest folder and then recursively deletes them all. For a version that has less changes, see below. Here we simply check a certain time later if the folder hasn't been deleted in the mean time.

```py
from os import listdir, rmdir
from os.path import exists, samefile
from time import sleep

def delete_empty_folders(top_folder: str, root_folder: str) -> None:
    """Keep deleting empty folders until we reach a folder with content
    or the root folder"""

    while True:
        if not exists(top_folder):
            top_folder = dirname(top_folder)
            continue

        if samefile(top_folder, root_folder):
            break
        
        if listdir(top_folder):
            # Check in 200ms if the folder still exists.
            # Could be that because of async folder deletion,
            #     the folder is submitted for deletion but not
            #     yet actually deleted.
            # Increase value for more safety.
            sleep(0.2)
            if listdir(top_folder):
                break

        rmdir(top_folder)
        top_folder = dirname(top_folder)

    return
```